# xs:choice implementation in tridion 

Tags: tridion

Can anyone explain implementation of choice in tridion

```
<xs:element name="person">
   <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice>
     <xs:element name="employee" type="employee"/>
     <xs:element name="member" type="member"/>
   </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
```

can anyone suggest the namespace related to choice  tag in tridion

Comment: Could you add some more clarity on what exactly are you trying to do in which part of Tridion and what version of Tridion are you using?

Comment: Version: Tridion SDL SP1 2011 , working to create a content schema which uses  <xs:group name="Xyz"> <xs:choice>...</xs:choice></xs:choice></xs:group> this kind of xsd code in it . But i'm unable to get this <xsd:group> in tridion namespaces, can you suggest one namespace which can implement this.

Comment: Do you want to do something special with this or do you just want to be able to select field value from the list of predefined values?

Comment: i want to create a schema which uses the XSD schema indicators like as we have <xs:sequence> tag, i would like to use in similar way <xs:choice> while creating an element of complextype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user978511: I believe what Jeevan wants to achieve (correct me if I'm wrong) is to offer a choice out of a set of FIELDS, not a choice out of a set of VALUES. This has never been supported by any Tridion GUI, and would automatically turn your schema into a 'complex' one, disabling the edit screen in the GUI for components based on the schema.
I agree with Chris that this is almost never a good idea. It would take a lot of effort to install another GUI to let end users handle this type of content. If you really need this functionality, you could direct those efforts towards Tridion's product managers, in the form of an enhancement request. The proper channel for this is http://ideas.sdltridion.com.

Comment: you are right!! 
like in normal xsd file how we use xs:choice tag  i wolud like to implement the same thing, while creating a content schema in tridion to check whether is there anything like  xsd:choice tag to implement the same.

and also please suggest me the tag in tridion which can implement the xs:group tag functionality while creating a schema in tridion.

Comment: can you think of any alternative if possible to achiev the same.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to be able to select field value from predefined values - then you should use List possibilities that are provided to you when creating schema. Just check **"Values will be Selected from a List:"** checkbox when creating a new text, number, or date field. You then will be able to provide values for your list or use category with keywords as values. You will also be able to define type of your list and some properties

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that if you create a Complex Schema (a Complex Schema is defined as any Schema which has features which are not supported using the SDL Tridion Schema building interface) for creating content in SDL Tridion, then you will not be able to use the GUI(CME) to create and edit content based on that Schema.

If that is an acceptable scenario, you can design any W3C compliant schema you like, and you don't need to use any SDL Tridion name-spaces.

However, I would like to point out that in 12 years of implementing Tridion, I have never seen a client requirement that actually needed to make use of complex schemas.